# Gradle build doesn't generate jar

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jar, build.gradle

I would like to build my project as a jar file which only contains my code.  This project jar is used as a library to other java project.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.my.lib'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}


dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

After I build the project (I am using IntelliJ, I clicked "Build" ==> "Rebuild project"). IntelliJ told me build successfully But I don't see any jar created. Why?

```
18:30:18: Executing tasks ':classes :testClasses'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
18:30:18: Tasks execution finished ':classes :testClasses'.
```

Comment: To create a Jar using the IDE use [Artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) settings page. If you want to use Gradle for creating the jar archive use corresponding Gradle task. See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:building_java_libraries

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that even I have those settings, when I choose Build->Build project, Intellij still not run Gradle build that's why in my original question there is no "sourceJar" showing. I have to open "Gradle tool" window, click on that little elephant icon to run gradle task. Then, type "Gradle build", it then run the source Jar task.

Answer (score 2):

The "Build Project" form IntelliJ IDEA will compile your code for usage in the IDE, it is not directly tied to the `build` lifecycle task of Gradle.

For Gradle to build the JAR, you need to run `./gradlew assemble`, which will have the expected outcome.
Note that this will not run tests or static analysis. If you want that to run as well, you can use `./gradlew build`.

Both of these Gradle tasks can be executed from the Gradle tool window in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in your file system and you might find it under the build/libs/.. folder

Answer (score 0):

If your code is showing build successfully that means it should generate one build file. In order to check it, you can search for the build file inside your project folder .and from there look for the lib folder. It should contain the jar file.
Sometimes build file is not showing in the IDE window, not sure about the reason but I found if it is under gitignore folder then it will not show that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).